# gridpanel ext.net communication failure error firefox

Tags: firefox, ext.net, gridpanel

I have a ext:gridpanel in my application and we have given the user the ability to arrange columns as per his convenience in the grid. 
We also have given a button reset columns to default so that user can go back to the original gridpanel column order.
A method is written in javascript file to bring back the grid to original state when the user clicks "Reset Column to Default button"
The click handler for this button calls the method-"gridpanel_restore"

The code for this method is:-

```
var gridpanel_restore = function (grid) {
try
{
    grid._State = appGlobal.getGridState(grid);
    if (grid._State == grid._DefaultState) {
        return;
    }
    grid._State = grid._DefaultState;
    var settings = Ext.decode(grid._State);

    var cm = grid.getColumnModel();
    if (cm.isLocked != null) {
        for (var i = cm.columns.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            if (cm.isLocked(i) && !settings.settings[0].lockField.contains(i)) {
                cm.setLocked(i, false, false);
            }
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < settings.settings[0].lockField.length; j++) {
            if (!cm.isLocked(i)) cm.setLocked(settings.settings[0].lockField[j], true, false);
        }
    }
    if (settings.settings[0].state.sort) { 
    }
    else {
        grid.store.sortInfo = null;
    }
    grid.applyState(settings.settings[0].state);
    var lastColumn = cm.getColumnAt(cm.columns.length - 1);
    cm.setColumnWidth(cm.columns.length - 1, lastColumn.width - 1, false);
    noMask = true;
    CMS.ResetUserSettings(grid._ControlID);
    if (settings.settings[0].state.group != null) {
        async: false
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    }
}
catch (err) {
}
```

}

This code works perfectly fine in IE but in firefox I get Communication failure on line "window.location.href = window.location.href;" on line 34
I have used this line because the page should be reloaded after setting columns to default otherwsise the grid does not render properly.
I have seen posts related to this but could not find a solution.

Please help. I have already asked this question in ext.net forum but no answer.

Comment: And why you do not use document.location.reload() ?

Comment: This is also not working. Getting the same error with this. Also even the column order does not reset if using this.

Comment: Is this syntax correct? {
        async: false
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    } may be should be { async = false; window.location.href = window.location.href;} ?

Comment: Not working still :( I think the syntax is not correct because while debugging the line  async: false  is not exceuted.

Comment: Just remove or comment this line and test

Comment: I already tried that. That works but in that case the grid does not render properly and its columns get cut. Only few columns are visible then.

Comment: Simplify jour example and post it on https://jsfiddle.net, then send me link to this example and I will fix it